# Diff в гите: одна строка или весь файл

Tags: git

Допустим есть некий файл отслеживаемый гитом. 
В данном файле поменяли пару строк, скажем в начале или в середине.

Воспользовавшись утилитой `gitk` можно посмотреть что именно менялось в файлах, однако тут возникает проблема т.к. **случай_1:** порой через утилиту гит подсвечивает только по паре строк что было удалено(-),а что добавлено(+), а порой **случай_2:** он содержимое всего файла помечает как (-) и заменяет на практически то же содержимое плюс доработки и помечает (+).

Вопрос: в каких случаях срабатывает **случай_1:** а в каких **случай_2:** и можно ли это как-то предугадать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в окончаниях строк. Иногда текстовый редактор, иногда сам гит меняет окончания строк во всем файле. Так бывает при несогласованной настройке гита на разных компьютерах.

Найдите настройку игнорирования различий в окончаниях строк при сравнении и воспользуйтесь ею.

Comment: Ок, Спасибо. Теперь ясно куда копать.

Answer (score 0):

**Случай_2** бывает только если вы принудительно удалили, а потом добавили файл с таким же названием. Иначе это **случай_1**, но реально изменены все строки. Просто изменены невидимые символы, например, перевод строки, пробелы, символы табуляции...

Comment: ну вот реальная практика показала, что случай_2 бывает и когда немного что-то поменяешь в файле. Собственно поэтому вопрос и возник.

Comment: Ну вы же сами пометили как лучший ответ, объясняющий, что это случай_1

Comment: Исходя с того, что я пометил как лучший ответ нельзя сделать однозначный вывод у меня был именно первый случай (появлялся и тот и другой, причем файлы вручную не пересоздавались). Полученный ответ меня вполне устроил, в отличие от ответа, полученного от вас. Продолжать дальнейшую дискуссию смысла не вижу. Всего хорошего.